# Receiving Albedo values from Landsat with Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am new to Google Earth Engine. I would like to extract the Albedo for certain areas of Greenland. I am doing it with MODIS as well as Landsat and was wondering the following about Landsat:

I found that you use the following equation for albedo:

```
((0.356*B1) + (0.130*B2) + (0.373*B3) + (0.085*B4) + (0.072*B5) -0.018) / 1.016
```

Does it make more sense to use 'USGS Landsat 8 Collection 1 Tier 1 TOA Reflectance' or 'USGS Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Tier 1' for that?

Comment: I think that is best answered by the source where you got the equation from

Comment: It says "Landsat image that has been converted from digital numbers to Top of Atmosphere (TOA) reflectance" but how do I know if the Landsat data in GEE is DN or TOA? couldn't find it in the information parts

Comment: I think GEE doesn't even have DN. TOA in this case would be 'USGS Landsat 8 Collection 1 Tier 1 TOA Reflectance'

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks for your help!